# Password doesn't update, but temporary code does!? PHP mail, user forgot password

Tags: php, sql, passwords

I made a webapp and I need to let the users change their password, so I made a column with temporary code. The thing is, my query does update my temporary code but won't update the password to the new password. Please some help, thanks in advance! ;)

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $code = $_SESSION['code'];
     $email = $_SESSION['emailneger'];
     $password = $_POST['password2'];
     $password1 = $_POST['password3'];
     $reset = $_POST['reset'];
     $tempcode = "";
     if($reset == $reset) {
       if($password == $password1) {
         $query =  "UPDATE consultant SET password = ?
                    AND tempcode = ?
                    WHERE email =  ? ";
         $qry=$db->prepare($query);
         $qry->execute(array($password, $code, $email));
         echo "<p>Uw wachtwoord is hersteld!</p>";
         $query = 'UPDATE consultant SET tempcode = ? WHERE email = ?';
         $qry=$db->prepare($query);
         $qry->execute(array($tempcode, $email));
       }  else {
         echo "<p>Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen.</p>";
       }
     } else {
       echo "<p>Je link is ongeldig, probeer nogmaals alstublieft!</p>";
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: if($reset == $reset) when does this fail?

Comment: @nikola http://ideone.com/qX1GK4 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update is incorrect. The syntax is

```
UPDATE yourtable SET field1=value1, field2=value, ...
                                  ^---
```

Note the `,` between the field/value pairs. You're using `AND`, which will be parsed/executed as

```
UPDATE consultant SET password = (? AND tempcode = ?) WHERE email =  ? 
UPDATE consultant SET password = ('foo' AND tempcode=123) WHERE email = 'foo@example.com')
UPDATE consultant SET password = ('foo' AND true/false) WHERE ...
UPDATE consultant SET password = true/false WHERE ...
```